# По какой причине ставится тире после вводного словосочетания?

Tags: тире, вводные-слова

***Он глубоко уважал своего друга, более того — восхищался им.***

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по какой причине ставится тире после вводного словосочетания в простом предложении? Тире ставится, потому что находится между однородными сказуемыми? 
И возможна ли постановка запятой вместо тире в этом предложении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Он глубоко уважал своего друга, бОлее того — восхищАлся им.***

Тире ставится на месте пропущенного местоимения ***он***. В этом случае вводное слово выделено логическим ударением, после него делается увеличенная пауза.

На том же основании тире ставится в предложениях с вводными словами ***с одной стороны, с другой стороны,*** например: Они, с одной стороны, не терпят фальши, а с другой ― очень доверчивы... http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_694

Рассмотрим вариант с обособлением запятыми: ***Он глубоко уважал своего друга, более того, восхищАлся им.***

При отсутствии тире вводное слово ***более того***  сложно выделить паузами при чтении, так как логическое ударение должно падать на однородные сказуемые. Тогда ***более того***  может быть прочитано как наречное выражение, отнесенное к глаголу, а не как вводное слово. В любом случае, ударение на вводное слово не падает, как в первом варианте с тире.

Comment: "Тире ставится на месте пропущенного местоимения он." — тогда получается, что это сложное предложение с двумя грамматическими основами. Так?